# Grid Search to find the best parameters for decision tree classification

Tags: r, classification, decision-tree

I have a dataset, whose Target variable is `Target`. I splitted the dataset into the Training set and Test set and I applied the decision tree classification:

```
library(rpart)
classifier = rpart(formula = Target ~ .,data = training_set)
```

I would like to apply Grid Search to find the best parameters, then I write:

```
library(caret)
classifier = train(form = Target ~ ., data = training_set, method = 'ctree')
```

obtaining

```
>classifier
Conditional Inference Tree 

8792 samples
   8 predictor
   2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 8792, 8792, 8792, 8792, 8792, 8792, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mincriterion  Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.01          0.8881768  0.4373290
  0.50          0.8936227  0.4350515
  0.99          0.8927400  0.4102918

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mincriterion = 0.5.
```

and

```
>classifier$bestTune
mincriterion
2          0.5
```

How can use now this value to improve my model?

Comment: you use ```train()``` to find the best hyperparamter. in this case, it is ```mincriterion```. You can try and predict using the final object from train.. what do you mean by improve your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
classifier = train(form = Target ~ ., 
                   data = training_set, 
                   method = 'ctree',
                   tuneGrid = data.frame(mincriterion = seq(0.01,0.99,length.out = 100)),
                   trControl = trainControl(method = "boot",
                                            summaryFunction = defaultSummary,
                                            verboseIter = TRUE))
```

I added a very broad range for your tuning grid, but since the optimal model had a mincriterion of 0.5, you may wish you limit the range. You can also replace `tuneGrid = data.frame()` with `tuneLength = 100` for example for caret to pick a grid of 100 automatically where you dont need to specify the mincriterion numbers. Also you can change the summary function from defaultSummary which shows Accuracy and Kappa to twoClassSummary which will give you metrics like sensitivity, specificity and ROC. If you do use twoClassSummary set `classProbs = TRUE` in `trainControl()` . You can also change the method from boot to cv of any fold. Have a look at `?trainControl`. Finally set a seed during model tuning for reproducibility.

Comment: Hi @zimia, thank you very much! I'm sorry but there is one thing I cannot understand. Where did you use the information about `mincriterion=0.5` in your code?

Comment: I didn't. What I mean is that because your first model showed `mincriterion=0.5` as the optimal out of the 3 values tested, it would be computationally expensive to test all `mincriterion` values from 0.01 to 0.99. A better approach would be to test a smaller range +/- around 0.5, e.g. 0.3 to 0.7 and iteratively narrow that range. For `ctree` this would not be too much of an issue as computations are quite fast but with other models, e.g. some ensemble tree based models or SVMs that can be computationally expensive  and may take several hours!